# What to expect after a power surge?

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, surge-protection, physical-damage

I have just experienced a power surge in my house and now my computer won’t turn on. I have pretty modern hardware including a Asus B550 pro 5 motherboard that has surge protection. I know something definitely fried since the computer won’t turn on, but what can I reasonably expect to be broken there (if I’m not completely unlucky)? Power supply? Motherboard? Additional components? And not only fried but a slowdown as well

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a power surge affects an electronic device, you cannot accurately predict exactly what gets damaged.

That is because the instantaneous current and voltage levels of a surge can be very high and so can bridge connections and circuits that are close together.

The only practical solution here is to take the computer to a local shop and have it assessed. If you are fortunate, a simple part or circuit may have sacrificed itself on behalf of more expensive parts.

There may be a surge protector on the board (per your question) and it may have internally opened.

But that is for a shop to assess.